# How to stop Multiline Json Read from returning a "_corrupted_record" when converting a request.response from an API request?

Tags: python, json, pyspark

The required task is to store json files from an API using PySpark. The code bellow works for responses without nested jsons, but when the response contains multiline jsons it stores a json file with "_corrupted_recrod":"". Is there a method that allows this transformation to give me a Json with nested json correctly?

The current code:

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

if response.status_code == 200 and len(response.json()) != 0:
    file = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([response.json()]))

    file.write.mode('overwrite').option("multiline","true").format("json").save(dumpPath)
    file.show()

else:
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Failed to get data from API. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    else:
        print(f"Delta is Empty. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

The cell output:

```
+--------------------+
|     _corrupt_record|
+--------------------+
|[{'encodedKey': '...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: use the `try-except` block.

Comment: or check the value of the `request.status`. if it is 200, then it is okay.